# JAX-RS Service Transaction Timeout

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions, jax-rs, ejb

How to configure transaction timeout value for JAX-RS Web Service implementation packaged in WAR archive? With EJB it's possible to configure the transaction timeout in deployment descriptor, but how to do this for JAX-RS endpoint?

Comment: AFAIK that's not possible if you are just deploying a reguar webapp (as a WAR file)

Comment: Might need to make your question clearer. Are you asking how to enforce timeouts from the serverside? What kind of timeout - Connection or Request?